# Automatically add woocommerce product short description on creation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a product short description by default whenever is the new product is being created. All the products will have the same short description, so there is no point keep copying and pasting it. So it should just be there when I click on the add a new product.

I would appreciate any help.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 
'single_product_short_description', 10, 1 );
function single_product_short_description( $post_excerpt )
{
global $product; 
if ( is_single( $product->id ) )
$post_excerpt = '<div class="product-message"><p>' . __( "Article only 
available in the store.", "woocommerce" ) . '</p></div>' . $post_excerpt;
return $post_excerpt;
}
```

I found the above code but couldn't get it to work :(

Thank you.
Regards,
Emre.

Comment: Where do you want this div appear on the frontend or the admin area?

Comment: Hi,
Admin area, please. Here is an example of what it is supposed to look like when the add product button is clicked.

Example: https://imgur.com/a/u1CSO

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

- Add this code inside your themes function.php
- Change the short description content as per your need - *"Here goes your short desc."*

```
    add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'cdx_add_product_short_desc' , '99', 1 ); 
    function cdx_add_product_short_desc( $data )
    {

          //only for product post type  
          if($data['post_type'] == 'product' ) { 

            //only if short description is not present
            if( '' == trim($data['post_excerpt']) ):

                $short_desc = 'Here goes your short desc.';
                $data['post_excerpt'] =  $short_desc ; 

            endif;
          }

        // Returns the modified data.
        return $data; 
    }
```

Comment: HI mate,
Thank you for your time to answer me. I added the code to the functions file but doesn't seem to work. When I click add the new product the short description is blank :(

Comment: I have tested this in my local server and it is working. Please do a little test for me replace this  `if( '' == trim($data['post_excerpt']) )`  with `if(1==1)` and then try to add a new product.

Comment: Really strange, I did what you said but didn't work again and i also disabled all of the plugins except Woocommerce to make sure it isn't a plugin conflict but still won't work :(

Comment: I created fresh WordPress server but still won't work. Could it be the theme or the fact that I'm using the latest woocommerce?

Comment: it works for me. But after click publish the post (not after open new product editor)

Comment: @chickensoup  My code is doing this on post save hook. You can do this when open new product using JavaScript/jQuery hook into wordpress admin footer (admin_footer).

Answer (score 0):

This will work to automatically override anything put into a product's short description field on the front-end only. It will not add the text to the backend field itself, which is good because it keeps it globalized if you need to change it later.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'filter_woocommerce_short_description', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_excerpt ) {
    $post_excerpt = '<div class="product-message"><p>' . __( "Article only available in the store.", "woocommerce" ) . '</p></div>';

    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your time to answer my query, but would it be possible to amend the code so that the text is shown on the backend. 

There is basically gonna be a small brand logo that needs to be added but above it going to be a small short description going to be typed. So it would be great if the text is visible on the backend.

Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/u1CSO

Thank you.